Record, and Export With PyAudio
Is there any way to have pyaudio record an mp3 when a button is being held down and stop recording and export the mp3 to the date and time when the button is released?
I have Python 3.
The button I’m using is a physical button on a Raspberry Pi.

First you need to install packages:
pip install pyaudio pydub RPi.GPIO

Install FFmpeg package:
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

Example:
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pydub import AudioSegment
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime

# Configuration
BUTTON_PIN = 17  # GPIO pin number for the button
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 0  # Not used directly in this case

# Initialize PyAudio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def record_audio(filename):
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    print("Recording started")

    frames = []
    while GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN) == GPIO.LOW:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    print("Recording stopped")
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    # Save to WAV file
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()

def convert_wav_to_mp3(wav_filename, mp3_filename):
    # Convert WAV to MP3 using pydub
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(wav_filename)
    sound.export(mp3_filename, format="mp3")

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN) == GPIO.LOW:
                # Button pressed: Record audio
                timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
                wav_filename = f"/home/pi/recordings/{timestamp}.wav"
                mp3_filename = f"/home/pi/recordings/{timestamp}.mp3"

                record_audio(wav_filename)
                convert_wav_to_mp3(wav_filename, mp3_filename)

                print(f"Audio saved to {mp3_filename}")

                # Remove WAV file if desired
                # os.remove(wav_filename)

                # Wait a bit to avoid multiple recordings from a single press
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)  # Polling delay

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting...")

    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        audio.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

